# How to make R output smaller? (For example, reduce the font size, margins etc)

Tags: r

I am trying to fit this output all on one page on overleaf. How would I do that?

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language = R]
> expand.grid(c(21:25), c(21:25), c(21:25))
```

```
    Var1 Var2 Var3
1     21   21   21
2     22   21   21
3     23   21   21
4     24   21   21
5     25   21   21
6     21   22   21
7     22   22   21
8     23   22   21
9     24   22   21
10    25   22   21
11    21   23   21
12    22   23   21
13    23   23   21
14    24   23   21
15    25   23   21
16    21   24   21
17    22   24   21
18    23   24   21
19    24   24   21
20    25   24   21
21    21   25   21
22    22   25   21
23    23   25   21
24    24   25   21
25    25   25   21
26    21   21   22
27    22   21   22
28    23   21   22
29    24   21   22
30    25   21   22
31    21   22   22
32    22   22   22
33    23   22   22
34    24   22   22
35    25   22   22
36    21   23   22
37    22   23   22
38    23   23   22
39    24   23   22
40    25   23   22
41    21   24   22
42    22   24   22
43    23   24   22
44    24   24   22
45    25   24   22
46    21   25   22
47    22   25   22
48    23   25   22
49    24   25   22
50    25   25   22
51    21   21   23
52    22   21   23
53    23   21   23
54    24   21   23
55    25   21   23
56    21   22   23
57    22   22   23
58    23   22   23
59    24   22   23
60    25   22   23
61    21   23   23
62    22   23   23
63    23   23   23
64    24   23   23
65    25   23   23
66    21   24   23
67    22   24   23
68    23   24   23
69    24   24   23
70    25   24   23
71    21   25   23
72    22   25   23
73    23   25   23
74    24   25   23
75    25   25   23
76    21   21   24
77    22   21   24
78    23   21   24
79    24   21   24
80    25   21   24
81    21   22   24
82    22   22   24
83    23   22   24
84    24   22   24
85    25   22   24
86    21   23   24
87    22   23   24
88    23   23   24
89    24   23   24
90    25   23   24
91    21   24   24
92    22   24   24
93    23   24   24
94    24   24   24
95    25   24   24
96    21   25   24
97    22   25   24
98    23   25   24
99    24   25   24
100   25   25   24
101   21   21   25
102   22   21   25
103   23   21   25
104   24   21   25
105   25   21   25
106   21   22   25
107   22   22   25
108   23   22   25
109   24   22   25
110   25   22   25
111   21   23   25
112   22   23   25
113   23   23   25
114   24   23   25
115   25   23   25
116   21   24   25
117   22   24   25
118   23   24   25
119   24   24   25
120   25   24   25
121   21   25   25
122   22   25   25
123   23   25   25
124   24   25   25
125   25   25   25
\end{lstlisting}
```

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, using a smaller font, but also two columns, because 125 lines is too much even for `\tiny`, that is already an insane font size. For instance:

```
% test.Rtex  in Overleaf or test.Rnw in Rstudio
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\begin{document}
\scriptsize
<<set,echo=TRUE>>=
expand.grid(c(21:25), c(21:25), c(21:25))
@
\end{document}
```

Said that, as the main purpose of any statistical software is understand the data without having to see every number, consider (**if possible**, of course) show only a sample of the data frame, for instance:

```
\head(expand.grid(c(21:25), c(21:25), c(21:25)))
```